# Align a PanelGrid which is in another PanelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, vertical-alignment

Hi everyBody I 'm searching for way to have a page like this picture[image: the hope]

without the banner(Only the part After it) 
I have tested all the issues about the  style vertical align ,  top and stuff like this and none worked for me so if anyone have any solution it will be greate and thank you

and this how my page look like actually (code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<style>
.className td{
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
<style>
.panelGridCenter {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<body>

    <ui:repeat var="offre" value="#{offreBean.offres}" varStatus="status">
        <h:link id="offre" value="#{offre.profilPrincipal}"
            fragment="#{offre.id}" />
        <br></br>
    </ui:repeat>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="classeName" style="display:block" >
        <ui:repeat var="offre" value="#{offreBean.offres}" varStatus="status">

            <span id="#{offre.id}"> 


            <h:panelGrid columns="2"
                    style="width:600px" >

                    <h:outputLabel value="Profil Principal : " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{offre.profilPrincipal}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Mission : " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{offre.mission}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Profil : " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{offre.profil}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Specificite du Poste : " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{offre.speceificitePoste}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Niveau Etude : " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{offre.niveauEtude}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Experience Mini : " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{offre.niveauExperienceMin}" />
                    <br></br>

                </h:panelGrid>


            </span>
        </ui:repeat>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2"  >
            <h:outputLabel value="Profil Principal" />
            <h:inputText value="#{offreBean.profil}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Contrat" />
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{offreBean.offres}"
                converter="ContratConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choisir Contrat :" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{offreBean.contrats}" var="contrat"
                    itemValue="#{contrat}" itemLabel="#{contrat.contrat}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputLabel value="Categorie" />
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{offreBean.categorieoffres}"
                converter="CategorieConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choisir Categorie :" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{offreBean.categorieoffres}" var="categorie"
                    itemValue="#{categorie}" itemLabel="#{categorie.categorie}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputLabel value="Mots Clés" />
            <h:inputText value="#{offreBean.motclé}" />

            <p:commandButton value="Chercher" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panelGrid>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you taken a loook at [<p:layout> component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/full.xhtml)?

Comment: yes but i must use only the panelgrid and the style to have the form i want

Comment: Check the generated HTML and ask about how to achieve it using the provided HTML and CSS.

Comment: any link where i can see what you are talking about ? @LuiggiMendoza thank you

Comment: When the view is generated and you can see it in your browser, press Ctrl + U (chrome or firefox) and you will see the generated HTML.

Comment: Additional to what @LuiggiMendoza said you can also open inspector. Press Ctrl+Shift+C in Firefox. There you can edit CSS, too.

Comment: i have tried but i wasnt able to have the view i want if anyone can help it will be great thank you @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Just deploy the project, open the page in your browser and check its source code **from the browser**. That's the generated HTML, and ask for guidance on how to edit that HTML using CSS to get your desired look

Comment: ah ok yes i m watching the code thank you ^^ so i must ask another question for editing that html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add this :

```
    <h:head>
        <style>
    .className td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

and

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="container" styleClass="className"
        style="display:block;">
```

and clean tomcat work directory, clean the browser cache and it working like a charme !!!!